# How to give external .yml file in Spring Boot Eureka Config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

I have multi-module Spring Boot Application. For the UserManager module I have userman.yml, userman-development.yml and also I have bootsrap.yml in resources part. However, I could not reach the userman-dev.yml. I set up the database url in userman-development.yml, as it does not see the userman-development.yml I am getting

## Error I Get

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles development are currently active).
```

Here is

## BootStrap.yml

```
eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 3
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 4
  client:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 1
    initialInstanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds: 4
flyway:
  enabled: false
spring:
  application:
    name: usermanager
    tomcat-timeout-minutes: 3
     
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${vcap.services.eureka-service.credentials.uri:http://127.0.0.1:8761}/config
      failFast: true
      retry:
        initialInterval: 2000
        multiplier: 1.5
        maxInterval: 4000
        maxAttempts: 30

server:
  port: 9100

endpoints:
  info:
    enabled: true
```

## userman-development.yml

```
spring:
   datasource:
      url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/`BUSDRIVERS"
      username: postgres
      password: 1
logging:
   level:
      com.iozer.example: DEBUG
      com.netflix.discovery.TimedSupervisorTask: "OFF"
dev:
   adminEnabled: true
```

How can Solve this ? What I am missing in this part ? Is my logic correct ?

## Thank You..

Comment: `spring.application.name` is set to `usermanager`, so shouldn't the file be called `usermanager-development.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

`the profiles development are currently active` - typically, the active profile `development` will be interpolated into something like: `application-{ENV}.yaml` - so you may need `application-development.yaml` or to update the profile name to `dev`.

Comment: Hello Rob, thanks for your replying but it still same. What is the proper way calling userman-development from bootstrap.yml ?  I mean what is the correct way ? I assume it does not see the userman-development.yml.

Comment: sorry - looks like the question has changed from when I initially read it. I can point you to https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html which might help ... sections 1.1 - 1.3 look relevant